# Select the dropdown value according to url value in php

Tags: php

I write this code for printing the price values up to 10000 using for loop  when I submit the form using get method the value of max_price is showing in the URL.
Now I want to select that value which is in URL when user refresh the page I tried to get  it but I didn't get success.Any solution for this?

```
<select name="max_price" id="max_price">        
                            <option value="">Max Price</option>
                            <?php  for($maximum=50;$maximum<=10000;$maximum=$maximum+500){ $price=($maximum)*(1000);?>
                            <option value="<?php echo $price;?>" <?php if(isset($_GET['max_price'])){ if ($_GET['max_price']==(($price)){?> selected <?php } }?>><?php echo "$".$maximum."K";?> </option> <?php } ?>
                        </select>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
<select name="max_price" id="max_price">        
    <option value="">Max Price</option>
    <?php  
        for($maximum=50;$maximum<=10000;$maximum=$maximum+500)
        { $price=($maximum)*(1000);

            echo "<option value=\"echo $price;\"";
             if(isset($_GET['max_price']))
            { if ($_GET['max_price']==$price)
                echo " selected ";
            }
            echo ">$".$maximum."K</option>";
            } ?>
</select>
```

Moreover in your source,
this line : `if(isset($_GET['max_price']))` is missing closing ) parenthesis.

Comment: Could you please explain ? it worked when i tried like , "http://localhost/1test.php?max_price=50" do you have any other plan ? I guess there could be error in other section if this is not working for you ... please enable error log in your server if not done so... As you did not get error in your code despite not putting closing bracket for if condition therefore there could other issues as well

Answer (score 0):

First, considering your Question, it is vital that you (at the least) expand your Code for readability. This is because, if your Code had been a little more readable, you would personally solve the issue.... There is nothing wrong with *inlining* your Code like you did... it is just only a bit of an extra-work to debug it (like in the current scenario).

```
<?php
    $selOptions        = "<select name='max_price' id='max_price'>" .PHP_EOL;
    $selOptions       .= "<option value=''>Max Price</option>" .PHP_EOL;
    for($maximum=50; $maximum<=10000; $maximum+=500) {
        $price         = $maximum * 1000;
        $selOptions   .= "<option value='{$price}' ";
        if (isset($_GET['max_price'])) {
            if ($_GET['max_price'] == $price) {
                $selOptions .= " selected=selected ";
            }
        }
        $selOptions   .= ">\${$maximum}K</option>" . PHP_EOL;
    }
    $selOptions       .= "</select> " . PHP_EOL;
    echo $selOptions;
```